# Is there anything wrong with the pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a problem in comprehending the mechanism of some lines of code in *binsearch function. Particularly, low and high are two pointers and are initialized as &tab[0] and &tab[n] respectively. In the next line i see that `low<high` i think it invalid because it's impossible to compare two addresses of two pointers. The next line also have the same problem. I do not know whether I'm right or not and I need some ideas from you all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXWORD 100
int getword(char *, int);
struct key *binsearch(char *, struct key *, int);
/* count C keywords; pointer version */
main()
{
    char word[MAXWORD];
    struct key *p;
    while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF)
        if (isalpha(word[0]))
            if ((p=binsearch(word, keytab, NKEYS)) != NULL)
                p->count++;
    for (p = keytab; p < keytab + NKEYS; p++)
        if (p->count > 0)
            printf("%4d %s\n", p->count, p->word);
    return 0;
}
/* binsearch: find word in tab[0]...tab[n-1] */
struct key *binsearch(char *word, struck key *tab, int n)
{
    int cond;
    struct key *low = &tab[0];
    struct key *high = &tab[n];
    struct key *mid;
    while (low < high) {
        mid = low + (high-low) / 2;
        if ((cond = strcmp(word, mid->word)) < 0)
            high = mid;
        else if (cond > 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It is very much possible to compare pointers when they point to elements of the same array. If you can add a number to a pointer to get another pointer, then you can subtract two pointers to get a number. Logical, isn't it?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. So in this case this want to show the position of the pointers in the array right?

Comment: Yes exactly. The result of comparing pointers is the same as the result of comparing corresponding array indices.

Comment: `NULL` is not equivalent to 0. There is a possibility that your programs crashes with that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly legal code. Excerpts from the standard (C11 draft)

6.5.8.5

> When  two  pointers  are  compared,  the  result  depends  on  the 
>   relative  locations  in  the address space of the objects pointed to. 
>   If two pointers to object types both point to the same  object,  or 
>   both  point  one  past  the  last  element  of  the  same  array 
>   object,  they compare  equal.   If  the  objects  pointed  to  are 
>   members  of  the  same  aggregate  object, pointers  to  structure 
>   members  declared  later  compare  greater  than  pointers  to 
>   members declared  earlier  in  the  structure,  and  pointers  to 
>   array  elements  with  larger  subscript values compare greater than
>   pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript.

Also,

6.5.5.9

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or  one  past  the  last  element  of  the  array 
>   object;  the  result  is  the  difference  of  the subscripts  of  the
>   two array elements.

In other words, it is legal to compare or subtract pointers pointing to elements within the same array (or one beyond the array). A subtraction yields the count of elements of the type being pointed to between the two pointers and a comparison provides information about which element is at a higher index in the array.

Now in the given code, the definition is:

```
struct key *low = &tab[0];
struct key *high = &tab[n];
```

Any comparison or subtraction between `low` and `high` or any other pointer of type `struct key` that points somewhere in-between them is legal.

Comment: I get it that we can compare between two pointers as in the case I've mentioned. However, if I write a line of codes like ``while(low=high++)``, is it legal? Because in the condition statement, for instance,I need to write ``==`` in case I want to compare the equality but is it different as in case of pointers?

Comment: @HoangNam Equality is also a valid operation on pointers. It will only return true if they are both pointing to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Two pointers can be compared if they are of the same array.

In particular these are the operation that you can do or not with pointers:

> - Pointer comparison is Valid only if the two pointers are Pointing to same array.
> - All Relational Operators can be used for comparing pointers of same type.
> - All Equality and Inequality Operators can be used with all Pointer types.
> - Pointers cannot be Divided or Multiplied.

So `low < high` is allowed and works well in this case.

Comment: "Two pointers can be compared if they are of the same array" ... or one past the last element of the array (as is probably the case here when `high == NKEYS`).